# Show $f$ differentiable $\iff$ $f(x) -f(x_0) = \psi(x)(x-x_0)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

The questions are a) to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable at the point $x_0$ if and only if $f(x) -f(x_0) = \psi(x)(x-x_0),$ where $\psi(x)$ is a function that is contiuous at $x_0$

b) if $f(x)-f(x_0) =\psi(x)(x-x_0)$ and $\psi \in C^{(n-1)}\left(U(x_0)\right)$, where $U(x_0)$ is a neightbourhood of $x_0$, then $f(x)$ has a derivative $(f^{(n)}(x_0))$ of order $n$ at $x_0$

I am having trouble with knowing what a correct proof is in this case and also with how to approach b)

If we assume $f$ is differentiable then $$f(x)- f(x_0) = f'(x_0)(x-x_0) +\alpha(x)(x-x_0)$$ and $\alpha(x) \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$ by definition.

Let $\psi(x) =f'(x_0) +\alpha(x)$. Then $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \psi(x) = f(x_0).$ Can I define $\alpha(x_0) = 0$ so $\psi$ to make continuous at $x_0$?

For the other direction  for $x \neq x_0$, $$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x) -f(x_0)}{(x-x_0)}=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\psi(x) = \psi(x_0)$$ which means that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

I'm not sure if this is correct so advice would be appreciated. Any hint with b) would also be.

Comment: Just a remark: for later studies this definition is really bad since it does not demand a linear approximation...

Comment: @Freeze_S To be fair the book does give the definition of a function being differentiable on a limit point $a$ if there exists a linear function $A(x-a)$ of the increment $x-a$ such that $f(x) -f(a) = A(x-a) +o(x-a)$. It also gives a more refined definition but I'm not too bothered with writing that here. Maybe I should have used that definition.  What I did post was considered equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't pose a good alternative definition of the derivative as Freeze_S pointed out, but it does test your knowledge of the standard definition.

For the forward direction, begin with the function

$$\psi (x) = \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

This function is defined everywhere but $x=x_0$. Use the differentiability of $f(x)$ to fill in that gap, and show your function satisfies continuity at $x_0$.

For the reverse direction, note the definition of the derivative at $x_0$ is:

$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} $$

You can directly prove the limit exists showing differentiability at $x_0$. As a hint, your desired limit will be $\psi(x_0)$.

Part B is similar to Part A but since you are given that $\psi(x)$ is $n-1$-times differentiable, you will be working with $\psi^{(n-1)}(x)$ instead.

Comment: A couple points. For the reverse direction, didn't I show the limit exist? For the foward direction, can you just define $\psi(x_0) = f'(x_0)$

Comment: Yes, your explanation looks good! For a limit, you do not need to consider the point $x_0$ as part of the definition. For your latter question, you can - now you need to show continuity.

Comment: Since $f$ is differentiable it is clear $\lim_{x \to x_0}\psi(x) = f'(x_0)$. This was actually what I intended with the previous comment. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm I seem to be having problem with part b) as well. The only thing I know is that $f'(x_0) =\psi(x_0)$ and not if then derivative of $f$ is defined on any other point, so how could I know it has $n$ derivatives at $x_0$ if $\psi$ is $n-1$ times differentiable?